# conditions of a maximal planar graph to be chordal

Tags: planar-graphs, chordal-graphs

what are the necessary and sufficient conditions of a maximal planar graph to be chordal?

a maximal planar graph is a graph such that addition of one more edge results in non-planar graph.

a chordal graph is a graph such that all cycles in graph of length $\geq$ 4 will have a chord in it.

Answer (score 2):

A maximal planar graph $G$ is chordal iff $G$ can be constructed from a triangle by recursively subdividing a triangle into three smaller triangles. They are also called Apollonian networks, planar 3-trees or uniquely 4-colorable planar graph (the last characterization is due to Fowler).

See the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_network) (and references therein if you are really interested).